# WPF datatemplate command

Tags: wpf, command, datatemplate, parameters

I've got a datatemplate for a tabcontrol's itemtemplate as follows;

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemTemplate">
        <DockPanel Width="120">
            <Button 
    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteTimeTableCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
    Content="X"
    Cursor="Hand"
    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
    Focusable="False" 
    Margin="0,1,0,0"
    Padding="0"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
    Width="16" Height="16" />
```

This is OK as it gives me a button in the tabcontrol to allow for deleting the current tabitem.

Trouble I'm having is that the Delete command I'm binding to has a canExecute method which updates all buttons across all of the tabs in the tabcontrol. I just want the current tab to be affected.

I've got property CanDelete which I want to include in my Command. I'm trying to find a good example on CommandParameters as I think this is the way I need to go.

Has anyone got a good suggestion for the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt that you still need help with this, but figured I'd take a crack at answering it anyway.

The way that I have done it in the past is to make the collection of items that you are binding to your TabControl be a collection of simple ViewModel objects. That way you can implement the CanXXX logic for each one of the tabs instead of the TabControl or view as a whole.

In this example, I am using the RelayCommand class that is shown in the [Josh Smith's MVVM article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TabBinding.ViewModels
{
    class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> _Tabs;
        public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> Tabs
        {
            get { return _Tabs; }
            set
            {
                _Tabs = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(this, "Tabs");
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            var tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>();
            tabs.Add(new TabViewModel() { TabHeader = "Tab1", Content="Content For Tab1" });
            tabs.Add(new TabViewModel() { TabHeader = "Tab2", Content = "Content For Tab2" });
            tabs.Add(new TabViewModel() { TabHeader = "Tab3", Content = "Content For Tab3" });
            tabs.Add(new TabViewModel() { TabHeader = "Tab4", Content = "Content For Tab4" });
            Tabs = tabs;
        }
    }
}
```

**TabViewModel.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows;

namespace TabBinding.ViewModels
{
    class TabViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        RelayCommand _CloseTabCommand;

        private string _TabHeader;
        public string TabHeader
        {
            get { return _TabHeader; }
            set
            {
                _TabHeader = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(this, "TabHeader");
            }
        }

        private string _Content;
        public string Content
        {
            get { return _Content; }
            set
            {
                _Content = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(this, "Content");
            }
        }

        public ICommand CloseTabCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_CloseTabCommand == null)
                {
                    _CloseTabCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        param => this.CloseTab(),
                        param => this.CanCloseTab
                        );
                }
                return _CloseTabCommand;
            }
        }

        public void CloseTab()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Close Me!");
        }

        bool CanCloseTab
        {
            get { return (TabHeader == "Tab2" || TabHeader == "Tab4"); }
        }
    }

}
```

**ViewModelBase.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TabBinding.ViewModels
{
    class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RelayCommand.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace TabBinding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A command whose sole purpose is to 
    /// relay its functionality to other
    /// objects by invoking delegates. The
    /// default return value for the CanExecute
    /// method is 'true'.
    /// </summary>
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;        

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new command.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
        /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;           
        }

        #endregion // Constructors

        #region ICommand Members

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion // ICommand Members
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TabBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TabBinding.ViewModels"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="360" Width="550">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="Data" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource Data}">
        <TabControl 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="10,10,10,10"
            Width="500"
            Height="300"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Button Content="X" Margin="0,0,10,0" Command="{Binding CloseTabCommand}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabHeader}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content}"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="TabBinding.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still interested about the answer, you can use the CommandParameter binding extension to pass the current model.

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteTimeTableCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

The passed object is going to be the DataContext of the tab item. The solution requires the ICommand implementation to handle the given parameter properly (casting etc). Furthermore, the RequerySuggested event should be raised after any modification on the model, since WPF cannot figure out when to requery the CanExecute methods on the tabs. Another thing to keep in mind when using asynchron programming models is to raise the refresh event from the UI thread only. Nothing is going to happen otherwise.